# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setTheResID')

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

The error is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setTheResID')`

It looks like the component throwing the error also may have another issue. When defining the store and doing the use the store1 is grayed out (doesn't show here):

```
import {useemarresidents} from '../store/emaresidents.js'
const store1 = useemarresidents()
```

Where it's used:

```
    methods: {    
        resSelected() {     
          this.store1.setTheResID(this.ResidentID)
          this.store.setThePage("Resident")
          this.$router.push({path: '/emarresidentdetails' });
        },
```

If I leave off the "this" I get store1 not defined.

store1:

```
actions: {
    setTheResID(setResident) {
        this.currResID = setResident;
     },
```

Why does dev work, but build (and publish) fail?

I expected the app to work the same in dev and build.

---

I thought it was vue 3 and Pinia 3. (Not sure what compiler-sfc means.) Vue and pinia not recognized t command level. Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "aplifyvue",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 4173"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^7.0.96",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "pinia": "^2.0.21",
    "vue": "^3.2.41",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5",
    "wave-ui": "^2.43.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.3",
    "vite": "^3.0.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to setup a basic counter store with vue3 and seems to work in both dev and production (build + preview), can you share the versions of vue, compiler-sfc and pinia that you are using?

Comment: Compiler SFC - means Single File component compiler which is used widely in Vue. Off, You cannot use "store" without pointing to it by "this" context in Vue context

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

Changed 2 things (not sure it they are related and don't want to spend time (other people's $) finding out.
Changed:

```
import {useemarresidents} from '../store/emaresidents.js'
to
import {useemarresidents} from '@/store/emaresidents.js'
```

And moved the store1 definition from the script start to the regular script data definition section.